# SwiftUI onDrag modifier delays UILongPressGestureRecognizer from beginning

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a UIKit view that's hosted in a SwiftUI view using `UIViewRepresentable`. This UIKit view contains a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`. The long press gesture is being used as a "hold down" gesture and has a `minimumPressDuration` of 0. As soon as you press down on the view, it will fire the gesture recognizer with the `.began` state. When you lift your finger, the `.ended` action is fired. We'll call the this `GestureView`.

I also have a view that uses the `.onDrag` modifier. We'll call that `DraggableView`

When I put `GestureView` and `DraggableView` in a view together, it causes a delay when firing the long press gesture recognizer action. This does *not* happen if I use a SwiftUI `LongPressGesture` on a normal SwiftUI view instead of the GestureView.

The `shouldRecognizeSimultaneously` delegate method is called twice. Once with a `SwiftUI.UIKitGestureRecognizer` that's in a failed state and shortly after with a `_UIDragLiftGestureRecognizer`, which is the one added by the `.onDrag` modifier. My long press gesture's action doesn't get called until *after* I get the call back with `_UIDragLiftGestureRecognizer`.

Why would a gesture recognizer on one view be affected by the recognizer that's added when using the `.onDrag` modifier on a *different* view?

I *think* I've tried all of the relevant `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` methods and `UIGestureRecognizer` properties that could prevent this from happening but so far it's not working. Is there anything I've missed? Some example code that reproduces the issue can be seen below.

Full Example:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @GestureState var holdingDown = false
    @State var isHoldingDown = false

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    .gesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 10000, maximumDistance: 10000).updating($holdingDown) { currentState, gestureState, _ in
                        gestureState = currentState
                    })
                Text("Fast")
            }

            VStack {
                GestureView(holdingDown: $isHoldingDown)
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                Text("Slow")
            }
        }

        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(holdingDown || isHoldingDown ? .red : .black)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .onDrag {
                NSItemProvider(object: "Hello" as NSString)
            }
    }
}

struct GestureView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var holdingDown: Bool

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        let view = UIKitGestureView(coordinator: context.coordinator)
        return view
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> MyCoordinator {
        MyCoordinator(holdingDown: $holdingDown)
    }
}

class UIKitGestureView: UIView, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    let coordinator: MyCoordinator

    init(coordinator: MyCoordinator) {
        self.coordinator = coordinator
        super.init(frame: .zero)

        backgroundColor = .orange
        let holdGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(holding(sender:)))
        holdGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0
        holdGesture.delegate = self
        holdGesture.delaysTouchesBegan = false
        holdGesture.delaysTouchesEnded = false

        addGestureRecognizer(holdGesture)
    }

    @objc func holding(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        switch sender.state {
        case .began:
            coordinator.holdingDown = true
        case .ended:
            coordinator.holdingDown = false
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        print(gestureRecognizer)
        print(otherGestureRecognizer)
        return true
    }
}

class MyCoordinator {
    @Binding var holdingDown: Bool

    init(holdingDown: Binding<Bool>) {
        _holdingDown = holdingDown
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I've found so far is to just check in `shouldRecognizeSimultanously` if my gesture is there and toggling the value myself.

```swift
    public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        if gestureRecognizer == holdingGesture && gestureRecognizer.state == .began {
            coordinator.holdingDown = true
        }
        return true
    }
```